# ¿Como escribir al inicio de un fichero sin sobreescribir datos en c#?

Tags: c#, archivo, filewriter

Quisiera saber como podría escribir datos al inicio de in fichero que ya existe pero solo agregarlos,sin que se sobreescriba los datos que ya estan. uso para escribir filestream y veo que puedo establecer la propiedadd seek para posicionarlo al inicio del archivo, pero si hao esto y escribo sobreescribo lo que hay en esa posicion no lo añade., el archivo donde necesito agregar los datos es muy grande por lo que no es opcion guardar toda la info en un array para agregar los datos y luego escribir el arraay, ya el archivo mas pequeño es de 500 GB y los mas grandes de gasta 1.5 TB

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el código que has intentado

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la solución podría ser usar un archivo temporal en el cual escribes el contenido inicial para luego adjuntar el contenido existente.

Se puede usar un bloque definiendo un buffer correcto basado en las especificaciones técnicas de la máquina que lo ejecuta, es decir, se podría armar un bloque de 100MB pero depende de la máquina que lo ejecuta.

Entre más pequeño el buffer mayor cantidad de ciclos se ejecutarán por lo que tomará más tiempo.

A continuación un pequeño código de demostración, no he capturado excepciones por lo que no aplicaría tal cual para producción, pero puede ser una solución:

```
string temp_file = "C:\\Temp\\temp.txt";
string source_file = "C:\\Temp\\final.txt";

using (System.IO.StreamWriter w = new System.IO.StreamWriter(temp_file)) {
    w.Write("*** "); //Contenido que se escribirá al inicio del archivo

    using (System.IO.StreamReader r = new System.IO.StreamReader(source_file)) {

        int size = 1024 * 1024; //1MB definir de acuerdo a la estación destino
        char[] buffer = new char[size];
        int bytes_read;//Contador de bytes leídos

        while (!r.EndOfStream) {
            bytes_read = r.Read(buffer, 0, size);
            w.Write(buffer, 0, bytes_read);
            }
        }
    }

System.IO.File.Delete(source_file);
System.IO.File.Move(temp_file, source_file);
```